# rails server not working WSL Insecure World

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Trying to run `gem install` and `rails server`, but I keep getting `/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:76: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777`

I've tried running the command `chmod go-w /mnt/c` which is what other posts say to do with this type of error. Doing so doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running:

- ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-linux]
- rbenv global rails-2.4.4
- gem "passenger", "5.2.1"
- Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Comment: any help from this https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1982

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately it didn't help to solve the issue.

Comment: I don't know ruby but why does it want to write in `/mnt/c`? And why not in `/home/user`? Can you redirect the write path from `/mnt/c` to `%LocalAppData%`?